# BAT working fine manually but generate error by VBA Shell

Tags: vba, shell, batch-file, vbscript

I used the shell function to run a BAT file that run a VBS script:

```
Shell ("C:\USERS\walaraji\Desktop\test1.bat")
```

The BAT File Command:

```
cscript c:\test\pbo.vbs
@pause
```

The BAT file works perfectly fine by clicking it manually but it generates error when I call it by VBA Shell

```
 Error: c:\test\pbo.vbs(7,1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object required
```

Comment: Publish (at least) line 7 of pbo.vbs.

Answer (score 0):

"bat" is not an executable file. In order to use it inside Shell you can directly run the vbs file using `Shell "cscript c:\test\pbo.vbs"` or `Shell "wscript c:\test\pbo.vbs"`

Comment: I tried to run the VBS directly inside Shell but it just do nothing, I changed the bat file to print a message only (just to make sure that shell function can execute the dos command inside the bat) and everything looks fine and the message appeared in cmd, but when I used bat to run vbs cscript c:\test\pbo.vbs instead there was error shows that the location c:\test\pbo.vbs(7,1) does not exist, I'm just not sure how and why the "(7,1)" has been added at the end of the location?

Comment: can you try the shell code from the run dialog and see if that runs without a hitch? did you try replacing cscript with wscript, or do you need the console window? a little more info on the lines of codes you are using would be helpful.. I ran a basic msgbox code at my end and it worked fine, but I used wscript